# How to display sql variable in the input tag of HTML?

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, textbox

I assigned the sql value in `$pid`, if i click the button, i wanted the `P_ID` value to be store in the `"value"`.

Code:

```
echo '<form>';
$pid=$row['P_ID'];
echo '<input type="text" name="history" value= '$pid'>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="View Patient History">';
echo '</form>';
```

However, I received few errors:

> SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
>   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';'

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$pid=$row['P_ID'];
echo '<form>';
echo '<input type="text" name="history" value= '.$pid.'>';  // This line will be change.
echo '<input type="submit" value="View Patient History">';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: hi..no error.. However, the textbox is empty.. i think the P_ID value is not been retrieved and assigned to $pid  @user3540050

Comment: Ok. then first of all print your array, and let me know your array.

Comment: Hey it worked.. i got the input from user and used '{$_GET["P_ID"]}'

Answer (score -1):

From the knowledge I've got from SO,

I think `echo '<input type="text" name="history" value= '$pid'>';` should be:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="history" value= '.$pid.'>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Just amend the third line of your code to say -

`echo '<input type="text" name="history" value= '.$pid.'>';`

instead of

`echo '<input type="text" name="history" value= '$pid'>';`

Answer (score -1):

You have to append the php variable to the string using dot operator

```
echo '<input type="text" name="history" value="'.$pid.'">';
```

Answer (score -1):

Use PHP [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) function  (`<<< EOF`), this way you don't need to escape any single or double quotes and it helps you to read the html code, it's a time saver.

```
<?php
$pid=$row['P_ID'];

echo <<< EOF
<form>
<input type="text" name="history" value= "$pid">
<input type="submit" value="View Patient History">
</form>
EOF;

?>
```

***DEMO***
http://ideone.com/YuYmBs